Fluid Dynamics: Interpreting Identity the product of the tensor identity in an integral (Suspension Dynamics)
I am currently studying a Fluid Mechanics course after a several year hiatus from university. Due to memory atrophy (and course coding changes) I am missing some prerequisite knowledge.
I have been self studying tensors and tensor calculus to bridge the gap.
I am struggling to understand how to how approach some of the integrals.
For calculating the drag force for a spherical particle in stokes flow we come across the following integral: (A Physical Introduction to Suspension Dynamics by Élisabeth Guazzelli, eq 1.15)
$$
\int_{S_p} \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot  \mathbf{xI} \cdot  \mathbf{n}^{out} dS
$$
I am failing to understand what $\mathbf{xI}$ represents here and how it should be interpreted.
In index notation I have taken the following approach
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{S_p} \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot  \mathbf{xI} \cdot  \mathbf{n}^{out} dS 
&= \int_{S_p} \rho g_i (x\mathbf{I})_{ij} n_j dS \\
&= \int_{V} \partial_j(\rho g_i (x\mathbf{I})_{ij}) dV  && \text{Divergence Theorem}\\
&= \int_{V} \rho g_i \partial_j((x\mathbf{I})_{ij}) dV  && \text{if $\rho$, $\mathbf{g}$ are uniform }\\
&= \int_{V} \rho g_i \delta_{ij} dV \\
&= \int_{V} \rho g_j dV \\
&= \rho \mathbf{g} \int_{V}dV = \frac{4 \pi a^3 \rho \mathbf{g}}{3}
\end{align}
$$
This is the expected answer but I have very much forced it. My main point of confusion is if $\mathbf{xI} = \mathbf{x}$ is a vector the whole integral statement doesn't make sense, (dot product of a dot product).
So I am guessing its meant to effectively take the scalar product of one of the dot products and turn it back in the vector so the second dot product can take place.
Overall I am lacking any certainty in approaching such a statement.

If any advice could be given on intuition regarding this it would be appreciated
If there are recommendations for a text book to gain familiarity and a more comprehensive understanding of handling tensors in calculus problems it would also be very appreciated.

Thanks.

I took a brief look at this book on google. After a promising start the author introduces $\mathbf{xI}$ right before that equation without properly defining the terms. Into the bin with it.

Read it as $(\rho g\cdot x)(I\cdot n)$.

When a physicist juxtaposes symbols, a dyadic product is implied (sometimes they'll use an explicit $\otimes$ symbol). This matches the interpretation in rural reader's comment.
